# Emergency Notifications

Tags: notifications, audio

Good Afternoon All,

I can't seem to find a solution to my problem when I do a google search so I'm hoping you all can help me.

I have an app on my phone which alerts me to nearby first aid incidents (GoodSAM), what I would like is to enable notification from that app to override any do not disturb or sound settings, I typically have my phone on silent or vibrate and in this instance it would be good to have it screaming out.

Any help would be most welcomed.

Kind regards,

Ollie

Comment: Your question seems to be about this app named "GoodSAM". In this case please edit the quest and add the link to Google Play Store as there are multiple apps with that name.

Comment: @Robert that shouldn't depend on the app, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions might depend on the Android version you're on. Take a look into *Settings › Apps & Notifications › GoodSam › Notifications* (available at least in Android 8+ – looks a bit different in Android 7 but is also there). In that place you should be able to define if it shall override DND.